# Are the solutions of a Sturm-Liouville equation entire in the spectral parameter?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

In $[1]$ the following (paraphrased) claim is made:

*Let $q\in L^1_{loc}([0,\infty);\mathbb{R})$, and suppose $\varphi$ and $\theta$ solve the one-dimensional Schrödinger equation
   \begin{equation}
      -u''(x;\lambda)+q(x)u(x;\lambda)=\lambda u(x;\lambda)~~~(x\in[0,\infty)),
   \end{equation}
subject to
   \begin{equation}
      \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         \varphi(0;\lambda)=0, &\varphi'(0;\lambda)=1, \\
         \theta(0;\lambda)=1,  &\theta'(0;\lambda)=0.
      \end{array}\right.
   \end{equation}
Then, for each fixed $x$, we have that $\varphi(x;\cdot)$ and $\theta(x;\cdot)$ are entire functions of order $1/2$.*

I understand from [a previous question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807841/proof-that-solution-of-lambda-affine-linear-ode-is-entire-in-lambda) that for entireness one needs the solution to obey a $\lambda$-independent initial condition (since otherwise specifying an i.c. non-analytic in $\lambda$ gives a counter-example), and $\varphi,\theta$ do exactly this.

Further than this I am fairly stumped, and in particular have no idea how to approach the claim on the order. Recall that the order of an entire function $f$ is
   \begin{equation}
      \rho:=\inf\{m\geq0~|~f(z)=O(\exp(|z|^m))\text{ as }|z|\rightarrow\infty\}.
   \end{equation}

Is it perhaps related to [the Gel'fand-Levitan integral transformation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VZPAyRmP8L8C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q&f=false), which allows one to write
   \begin{align}
      \varphi(x;\lambda)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt\lambda x)}{\sqrt\lambda}+\int_0^x K(x,t)\frac{\sin(\sqrt\lambda t)}{\sqrt\lambda}\text{d}t, \\
      \theta(x,\lambda)=\cos(\sqrt\lambda x)+\int_0^x K(x,t)\cos(\sqrt\lambda t)\text{d}t?
   \end{align}
Here $K$ satisfies
   \begin{align}
      K_{xx}&=K_{tt}+q(x)K(x,t), \\
      2\frac{\text d}{\text dx}K(x,x)&=q(x),~K_t(x,0)=0.
   \end{align}

$1$. Bennewitz, C., *A proof of the local Borg-Marchenko theorem*, Commun. Math. Phys. $218$, pp. $131$--$132$ ($2001$).

Answer (score 2):

This is a little too long for a comment. I wonder if the standard Picard iteration would work. If you want a solution $u$ with $u(0)=A$ and $u'(0)=B$, then
$$
\begin{align}
      u'(x) & = B+\int_{0}^{x}(q(x_1)-\lambda)u(x_1)dx_1, \\
      u(x) & = A+Bx+\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x_2}(q(x_1)-\lambda)u(x_1)dx_1 dx_2 \\
      & = A+Bx + \int_{0}^{x}(x-x_1)(q(x_1)-\lambda)u(x_1)dx_1.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this helps, e.g., find the $\lambda$-derivative of a solution.

Comment: If you iterate, then you'll see that the iterates (a) are polynomials in $\lambda$ and (b) converge uniformly for $x$, $\lambda$ in some bounded sets. That's enough to give you analytic solutions in $\lambda$. And you can interchange orders of $x$, $\lambda$ derivatives to get $-(\partial_{\lambda}u)''+q(\partial_{\lambda}u)=u+\lambda(\partial_{\lambda}u)$ with $\partial_{\lambda}u$ and its first derivative vanishing at $a$ in my case.